# CSS have element in the middle over two elements

Tags: html, css

I have these 3 elements: checkout-left, checkout-right, product-2

```
<div class="order-form">
                                <div class="checkout-left">
                                        <div class="video another-video">
                                                <div class="video-wrapper second-video">
                                                        <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="221" height="169">
                                                                <source src="magnet.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                                        </video>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <img src="http://magnaboss.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/checkout-right.jpg" style="float: right;" />
                                <img src="http://magnaboss.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/product-2.png" class="product-2" />
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
```

what I am trying to do is have the element product-2 overlap checkout-left and checkout-right and it right in the middle without position:absolute

Here is the CSS

```
img.product-2
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-12deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
    width: 200px;
}

.order-form {
        background-color: #FFF;
        max-width: 900px;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.checkout-left {
        background: url(http://magnaboss.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/checkout-left.jpg);
        width: 450px;
        height: 380px;
        float: left;
        border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code.......it pushes down the checkout-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a negative `margin-left` and positive `translateX` to product-2

```html
img.product-2
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-12deg) translateX(100px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg) translateX(100px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-12deg) translateX(100px);
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

=================================================

**EDIT: Here's another method:**

Remove `float:right` from **checkout-right**

```html
<img src="http://magnaboss.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/images/checkout-right.jpg" />
```

Then modify **product-2** like so:

```css
img.product-2
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-12deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
    width: 200px;
    /* Add these lines */
    margin-top: -385px; /* Adjust if necessary */
    margin-left: 350px; /* Adjust if necessary */
    float: left;
}
```

And lastly, add `white-space: nowrap` to the **.order-form** container

```css
.order-form {
        background-color: #FFF;
        max-width: 900px;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        /* This line prevents checkout-right from moving down */
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

To watch a live example visit: http://codepen.io/wilman/pen/xZowgG